# Unable to get past 404 error with Jersey

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I've been looking for days for a solution to this issue, I am completely lost as to why I keep getting 404 errors on my local server.

I started a new project from scratch, with only a single servlet and without any success.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TheQuestionnaireDatabase</groupId>
    <artifactId>TheQuestionnaireDatabase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>The Questionnaire Database</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
    <display-name>TheQuestionnaireDatabase</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QuestionnaireApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.damsky.danny.questionnaire.QuestionnaireApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.damsky.danny.questionnaire.servlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>QuestionnaireApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

QuestionnaireApplication.java

```
package com.damsky.danny.questionnaire;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public final class QuestionnaireApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    static {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public QuestionnaireApplication() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        packages("com.damsky.danny.questionnaire.servlet");
    }
}
```

WelcomeServlet.java

```
package com.damsky.danny.questionnaire.servlet;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/welcome")
public final class WelcomeServlet {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String showWelcomePage() {
        return "<h1>Hello</h1>";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
In case it's of any importance: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, Tomcat 9.0.10 and Java 8.

Update:

To access the servlet I'm using localhost:8080/welcome
(I checked that the application context is /)

Comment: Do you see the print statements in the ResourceConfig being called on startup? Also what URLs are you trying?

Comment: Have you looked at the server logs?  Have you tried request logging?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663616/tomcat-request-logging-how-to

Comment: Update your post with the URL(s) you are submitting to get 404. Without that information your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha The print statement do not show. Updated the post with the URLs

Comment: @skomisa Added URLs to the post

Comment: I'm not sure what tutorial you were reading, but it's probably making a huge misinstruction. The `WelcomeServlet` class as you have there does **absolutely not** represent a web servlet, but it instead represents a JAX-RS resource. So the correct class name would have been `WelcomeResource`, and equivalently the `com.damsky.danny.questionnaire.servlet` package must be renamed to `com.damsky.danny.questionnaire.resource`. To understand what servlets really are, head to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, I changed it to resource in my project, and I read what you sent me. Still, what I'm trying to understand is why my project doesn't "see" the Java classes.

Comment: If your ResourceConfig is not running then it seems that your code is not getting deployed to the server. I'm not sure. I never use the server integration with the IDE. I always just run from a Maven plugin, like the [maven-jetty-plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html).

Comment: You can try to put a breakpoint at the Jersey [`ServletContainer#init()`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.27/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.java#L370) to see if it is called. If this is not called, then for sure you code is not getting deployed.

Comment: You figure anything new out?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have servlet mapping for "/welcome"

Either you can change mapping from `@Path("/welcome")` to `@Path("/")` in WelcomeServlet.java

Or add new servlet for url-mapping @Path("/")

```
package com.damsky.danny.questionnaire.servlet;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
public final class IndexServlet {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String showPage() {
        return "<h1>Index</h1>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not following you. I tried setting it to "/" and it doesn't work either. The servlet-mapping is set for the entire Jersey application, and it's set to /* so that every sub-path should be associated with a Java Jersey servlet. Having my servlet set-up the way I did I was expecting to see it open on localhost:8080/welcome

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue was with maven. It seems to follow a specific project structure, one that's different from the regular Java EE project structure. Starting a new Maven project in IntelliJ and working with Maven's own project structure fixed the issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to put all Jersey related Jars in the lib folder of `WEB-INF`

You can do this in IntelliJ under `Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts`